# All URI opening the homepage in a new React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am just getting started with React, and created a new React project using the create-react-app CLI command. Then I fired up the app using npm start, which works as expected and launched an instance of the test app running on http://localhost:3000/.

However, when I try to open a random URL like http://localhost:3000/test or http://localhost:3000/abcd, that also loads to the same homepage. Shouldn't I get a 404 for these URLs?

Any explanation about this behaviour would be appreciated, and I would also like to know how to change the behaviour to actually display a 404 page for URLs which have not been declared through the React Router.

Comment: show your `routes` file.

Comment: There is no `routes` file. I have not made any changes to the initial app code which gets generated from create-react-app.

Comment: you need react-router for that

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Hello from './Hello';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Hello} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Try this you need to install react-router

> npm install react-router-dom

Here the NotFound is the 404 page